# Ruby 2.4 and BigDecimal error (invalid value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal

Given a value in a hash like this:

```
billed_amt:""
```

This code then:

```
BigDecimal.new(tt[:billed_amt].to_s)
```

results in this error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid value for BigDecimal(): ""
```

Is this correct behaviour?  I have tried updating the gem with no luck.

Comment: you may want to convert `""` or `nil` to 0 before passing to `BigDecimal`. `BigDecimal(tt[:billed_amt].to_i)`. or you can use `to_d` method `tt[:billed_amt].to_s.to_d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. You can read about it in "[BigDecimal fix for Rails 4 with Ruby 2.4](https://jamescrisp.org/2017/09/26/bigdecimal-fix-for-rails-4-with-ruby-2-4/)".

Big Decimal 1.3.0, which ships with Ruby 2.4, was changed to throw an exception on invalid values to the constructor rather than returning 0 as it did in Ruby 2.3. This was done so that it was more consistent with the other numeric types (Integer, Float, e.t.c.).

There have been [suggestions to revert this functionality](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/issues/95) however it is likely it won't happen as BigDecimal needs to be consistent with the other numeric types.